# MediaPlayer error on QT5.5 with IOS9

Tags: ios, qt, qml

After updating my QT to 5.5 and my IOS to 9, I tried to run my app on my iphone 5s. My app is a simple Podcast App, that plays audios saved on an AWS S3 storage. Everything worked fine before. But now it's not loading the audios. After checking the status of the MediaPlayer, I got the value 8 (QMediaPlayer::InvalidMedia).

The error only happens on my iphone, when I run it on the desktop, everything works!

I tried with a local MP3 file and it works, but my problem is with MP3 from an URL.

How can I solve this?

Regards,
Renato.